# How to use an HTTP proxy in java

Tags: java, proxy, ip

I am writing a code that connects to websites and checks some code, like a crawler. But I need to connect trough a proxy and change the IP address (so it doesn't show the client's IP in the server logs).

How can this be done through java?

Comment: hmm you sound like your up to something good.

Answer (score 49):

You can use the java system properties to set up a proxy or pass it as command line options.

You can find some details and samples [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html).

Ex: Before opening the connection

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myProxyServer.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

Or you can use the default network proxies configured in the sytem

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

Since Java 1.5 you can create a instance of proxy and pass it to the `openConnection()` method.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.0.0.1", 8080));
URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
uc.connect();
```

Or as [lisak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599933/how-to-use-proxy-in-java/4599968#4600039) suggested, you can use some 3rd party libraries which supports your need better.

Comment: You should also note that the proxy configuration for HTTPS uses a slightly different property eg. System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myProxyServer.com");. I was wondering why this wasn't working for me at first and it was because my code uses HTTPS.

Comment: Why is there no Proxy.Type.HTTPS (secure) constant at all?

Answer (score 10):

Or you can also use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org) which would suit your needs better. Check out the documentation, it's brief and very informative.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("someproxy", 8080);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Comment: Tutorial here: [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e475)

Answer (score 0):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.0.0.1", 8080));
URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
uc.connect();
```

This worked for me. I was able to use the proxy for the specific connection or transfer. Earlier we were using System.setProperty which used to set it at system level and all the requests internal/external started using the same proxy.

Also Proxy.Type.HTTP works for both http and https

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by adding below line before opening connection.

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

In case you need to use a specific proxy you can even set that in system properties.